# Loading a BigInteger with a large, positive, number

Tags: java, android, biginteger, uint, uint64

I'm trying to port a code from .NET which uses UInt64 everywhere, I've mostly succeeded using BigInteger, but unfortunately I've become stuck at something really simple as loading a BigInteger with a value from a table of hex values.

At some point I want to load a BigInteger with the **positive** 0x990951BA, only way I saw to do this was with BigInteger b = BigInteger.valueOf(0x990951BA), this of course does not work because Java treats the argument as a long, making it negative.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`long` is 64-bit in Java, so you should be able to use it as a direct substitute for `UInt64`. To specify a `long` literal, append an `l` to the constant to have it recognized as `long` rather than `int`.

```
BigInteger b = BigInteger.valueOf(0x990951BAl);
```

A fallback for values which are too big even for long is to parse it as text.

```
BigInteger b = new BigInteger("990951BA", 16);
```

Comment: Been working with C# far too long! :) thank you, I hadn't realised Java was treating my hex value as an int instead of a long!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're porting code that uses unsigned longs, you may also want to look into [UnsignedLong](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedLong.html) from [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).  (And also the UnsignedLongs helper class in the same package).